# How to disable a USB port

Tags: usb, power-management

The cable connecting the webcam and my laptop seems to be broken.  As a result, the webcam keeps connecting and disconnecting all the time.  Is it possible to disable a USB port?

A sample of the `dmesg` output.  It is really annoying when I'm trying to diagnose other system problems.

```
[ 2137.301986] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[ 2137.459229] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2137.459231] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2137.459232] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2137.459233] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2137.462279] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2137.486895] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input98
[ 2143.584635] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 61
[ 2143.950031] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 62 using xhci_hcd
[ 2144.107491] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2144.107497] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2144.107500] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2144.107503] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2144.110929] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2144.132345] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input99
[ 2153.096693] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 62
[ 2153.429937] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
[ 2153.587337] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2153.587343] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2153.587346] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2153.587349] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2153.590733] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2153.613767] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input100
[ 2157.458170] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 63
[ 2157.797920] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[ 2157.955190] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2157.955196] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2157.955199] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2157.955202] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2157.958597] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2157.986659] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input101
[ 2168.693293] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 64
[ 2169.021824] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[ 2169.179331] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2169.179337] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2169.179340] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2169.179343] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2169.185007] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2169.210042] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input102
[ 2175.249614] usb 1-12: USB disconnect, device number 65
[ 2175.573763] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 66 using xhci_hcd
[ 2175.731137] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=2c01, bcdDevice=65.03
[ 2175.731143] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2175.731147] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated Webcam
[ 2175.731150] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: SuYin
[ 2175.734499] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Webcam (1bcf:2c01)
[ 2175.754927] input: Integrated Webcam: Integrated W as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input103
```

Occasionally, different messages will show up

```
[24595.350828] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[24595.478920] usb 1-12: Device not responding to setup address.
[24595.686871] usb 1-12: Device not responding to setup address.
[24595.894834] usb 1-12: device not accepting address 32, error -71
[24596.806940] usb usb1-port12: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[24596.807057] usb usb1-port12: attempt power cycle
[24598.243000] usb usb1-port12: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Comment: Is this a built-in webcam?

Comment: @roaima Unfortunately, yes.  Otherwise I would have thrown it away.

Comment: You can either disable the (internal) usb hub it attaches to completely, or some *rare* usb hubs have a per-port setting: https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl#compatible-usb-hubs

Comment: You could take a look at my answer to this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493607/usb-device-is-not-responding-to-set-address/494320#494320 . Just have an external keyboard or remote access when testing this, in cases this stops the internal keyboard too

Comment: If you're lucky you can use runtime PM management for USB ports. The documentation is here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/driver-api/usb/power-management.html#user-interface-for-port-power-control - it's not applicable to my laptop, so I cannot test whether it actually works.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the pointer.  I tried to follow the document, but several files do not exist in my system.  I guess it is not applicable to my laptop.

Comment: @A.B I tried your answer.  It works, but I actually need other USB devices.  Moreover, I found that writing `1` back to `authorized` will not re-enable the USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated webcam, if you are lucky, can be individually disabled by BIOS.

This solves my problem, but it is not a generic solution.