# USB stick: device not accepting address, error -71

Tags: usb-drive, usb-device

###### Problem

Recently, my USB stick been unrecognized by the OS. 
Therefore I would like to copy it entirely on my hard disk drive asap.
However, neither on windows nor linux, the USB stick appears.

###### Description

- On windows, I'm only able to heard the sound for new USB material connexion.
- On linux (I'm using a debian 10), **dmesg** (similarly to **journalctl** command) gives me

  ```
  $ sudo dmesg | tail
  [ 1680.983731] usb usb1-port11: attempt power cycle
  [ 1681.399621] usb 1-11: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
  [ 1681.399827] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
  [ 1681.607797] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
  [ 1681.815602] usb 1-11: device not accepting address 9, error -71
  [ 1681.943616] usb 1-11: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
  [ 1681.943796] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
  [ 1682.151791] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
  [ 1682.359635] usb 1-11: device not accepting address 10, error -71
  [ 1682.359742] usb usb1-port11: unable to enumerate USB device
  ```

  but neither **lsusb** nor **lsblk** nor **fdisk** show me the USB stick.
  Therefore, as the material does not appear in /dev/sda list, I cannot use **dd**, **testdisk** or whatever to rescue data.

###### Attempts

I tried several solutions

- change the grub to accept the old_scheme [ https://askubuntu.com/questions/117524/usb-device-not-accepting-address ]
- unplugged others USB material or replugged [ https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error ]
- try to use old_scheme (or both_scheme) and cancel autosuspend with the following commands

  ```
  echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
  echo Y > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/use_both_schemes
  ```

  as mentionned in [ https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789&page=2 ] and [ https://askubuntu.com/questions/262141/usb-error-71-eproto-with-a-gamepad ].

but everything was unsuccessful :(.

###### Finally

As USB stick doesn't show itself in /sys/bus/usb/devices/ (at least I wasn't able to see it), I don't try
[ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493607/usb-device-is-not-responding-to-set-address ].

Also, as USB stick is not mentionned with **lsusb**, I'm not able to test this solution
[ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712346/accessing-files-in-usb-device-thats-listed-on-lsusb-command?rq=1 ].

Do you have any idea to be able to list the stick with **lsusb** or **fdisk**, or better to solve the problem ?

Thank a lot

Comment: if the "usb stick" doesn't show up, then it'll take a professional with professional equipment to have any chance to recover the data on it